# display image in servlet

Tags: java

I am having the following requirement.
When the user cliock the buton the image should be displayed.The following code that i have tried gives me error

```
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Image ima = Toolkit.getImage("C:\\DB.jpg");
    MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(new Canvas());
    mt.addImage(ima, 0);
    try 
    {
        mt.waitForAll();
    }
    catch(Exception x)  {}
    OutputStream os = res.getOutputStream();
    // Now create a writable image,
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(ima.getWidth(null), ima.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    bi.drawImage(ima, 0, 0, null); // Draw the loaded image onto a writable thing
    JPEGImageEncoder je = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(os);
    je.encode(ima);
    os.close();
}
```

Comment: what error do you get? And please put your code in a format block.

Comment: Is the image eventually going to be dynamically generated?

Answer (score 1):

Before calling `res.getOutputStream()` have you first made sure you have called `res.setContentType("image/jpeg")`?

Comment: and if you want to be absolutely sure (because every container spec is different) you could res.flushBuffer() when you are happy you are done